# How would I make a form which searches for values in all tables of a database in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to make a form which searches for the value inside all of the tables in the database (there are more than 1 table). The result will be displayed as the name of the table which this appears in. If someone can help me that will be nice.

In short, I have a form with a textbox and button. I enter the search string (for example 183939) and click on the button. It searches the value (183939) inside all the fields in the tables in the database, and if the value is found, then it displays the name of the table that it appears in. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bad idea because it could take a very long time, and provide confusing results due to also searching system tables... but the following function will return an array of all table names containing the search term or nothing if it wasn't found. Calling example is such: `theTables = containingTable("hello")` where theTables is a variant. A limitation is that this will fail for multi-valued fields.

```
Function containingTables(term As String)
    Dim db As Database
    Dim tds As TableDefs
    Dim td As TableDef
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set tds = db.TableDefs
    For Each td In tds
        For Each f In td.Fields
            On Error Resume Next
            If DCount("[" & f.Name & "]", "[" & td.Name & "]", "[" & f.Name & "] LIKE '*" & term & "*'") Then
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
                    Err.Clear
                    On Error GoTo 0
                Else
                    containingTables = containingTables & td.Name & ","
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Set tds = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    'Alternate Version
    if Len(containgingTables) then containingTables = Left(containingTables, Len(containingTables) - 1)
    'Original Version
    'if Len(containgingTables) then containingTables = Split(Left(containingTables, Len(containingTables) - 1), ",")
End Function
```

To display the results with the alternate version, just use: `Msgbox(containingTables(searchTerm))` where `searchTerm` is whatever you are searching.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I know that this is a bad idea, but there isn't much I can do about it as it is set in stone to me. So all I need to do is paste this code into the VBA page, and then when I run the form, and press search, the result will pop up?

Comment: No, this is just a function that you can use to obtain an array of strings that has the name of all tables that have the search term as part of the contents of some field (excluding multivalue fields). You would need to process the array. Alternately, If you get rid of the Split in my last line, you could have a comma delimited string returned instead that you could just display in a msgbox... I'll update my answer to show you.

Comment: You can adapt it to handle muti-valued fields.  If `f.Properties("AllowMultipleValues") = True`, then use a variation of your `DCount()` expression: `DCount("[" & f.Name & "]", "[" & td.Name & "]", "[" & f.Name & "].Value LIKE '*" & term & "*'")`

Answer (score 0):

Me as well i don't know why you would want to do something like that...

I think the solution posted by Daniel Cook is correct, i just took a slightly different approach. Do you need to match the exact value like I do? Anyway, here's my code:

```
Function searchTables(term as String)
  Dim T As TableDef
  Dim Rs As Recordset
  Dim Result() As String
  Dim Counter

  Counter = 0
  For Each T In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If (Left(T.Name, 4) <> "USys") And (T.Attributes = 0) Then

      Set Rs = T.OpenRecordset
      While Not Rs.EOF
        For Each Field In Rs.Fields
          If Rs(Field.Name) = term Then
            Counter = Counter + 1
            ReDim Preserve Result(Counter)
            Result(Counter) = T.Name & "," & Field.Name
          End If
        Next
        Rs.MoveNext
      Wend
      Rs.Close

    End If
  Next
  If Counter = 0 Then
    searchTables = Null
  Else
    searchTables = Result
  End If
End Function
```

You should filter out duplicated values, in case the function matches multiple times the same filed in the same table.

Comment: Alternately, you could upon finding a result use `rs.MoveLast` and `Exit For` to get to the next table.

Comment: I didn't read you comment so I update mine! Yes if he just needs to show the name of the table, and not the name of the field, he could skip reading the whole table once he finds a matching field.