# How to find where the information is stored when entered through a form?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have an already created database in MS Access 2003. It has forms that are used to enter data into tables. I want to create a report that shows the values entered through the forms. I am trying to find where the data gets stored when entered through the form so that I can create a report on that table, and I am not able to find it. Can someone please tell me how I can do this?

Comment: maybe you need something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901458/how-would-i-make-a-form-which-searches-for-values-in-all-tables-of-a-database-in

Comment: Can you open the form in design view and look at the query or table which is its record source?

Answer (score -1):

I would add an additional field to your back end tables, and write the name of the form directly into the record. That way you can query it later.

Comment: There are so many tables in the database, should I query all the tables to find out where information is going? And then that would give me an overhead of adding and deleting fields in the tables

Comment: I am afraid I consider this to be a very strange answer and I cannot see that it has any real value.